# Goal-seek Macro Loop that skips blanks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA. I've been trying to learn by trying, and reading forums, but I'm at a loss.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=1, ChangingCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is what I found on the forums more or less, and it works for a column with random numbers, which is good. But I need it to skip blank cells. Alternatively, I need it only apply the macro to visible cells (when filtered).

I've found answers to this question, but I don't know how to insert them into my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro()

Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" then GoTo here
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=1, ChangingCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)
here:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Try this